# How to find if a number is perfect number with a recursive code

Tags: python, recursion, perfect-numbers

So I want to write a func which get a number and return True if it a "perfect number".
I need to do it without using for or while in my function.
Here is what I tried to do -

```
def question_1(num):
i = 1

def checkDivide(n, num):
    if num % n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return 0

def SumThemAll(num, i):

    if i == num:
        return 0
    else:
        return i + SumThemAll(num, checkDivide(i + 1, num))

if num == SumThemAll(num, i):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

The problem is when I get to an integer which does not divide with the number i want to check
but I dont know how to fix it.
any idea how to make it more fast will help too

Comment: I edited my answer to get rid of some unnecessary stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def perfect(num: int):
    def recursive(num: int, i=1):
        if num == i:
            return 0
        elif num % i == 0:
            return i+recursive(num, i+1)
        else:
            return recursive(num, i+1)
    return False if num < 2 else recursive(num)==num
```

And the non-recursive solution just to check:

```
def non_recursive(num: int):
    return sum(i for i in range(1, num) if num%i==0) == num
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution. However, it comes with a **WARNING**.

The largest value that this can process is 1994 before a RecursionError is raised.

```
def isperfect(n):
    def isperfect_(n, m, s=0):
        if m == 0:
            return n == s
        if n % m == 0:
            s += m
        return isperfect_(n, m - 1, s)
    return False if n < 2 else isperfect_(n, n//2)
```

Comment: Doesn't that depend on your recursion limit? With a recursion limit of 3000, the maximum value that doesn't give me a RecursionError is 5941.